# Python tkinter new or open screen

Tags: python, tkinter, file-type

I use Python tkinter module to make my program. How can I make when the user opens the program he gets two buttons, or make a new project, or open. They can save the project as a custom file type and open it and everything is back what they did. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a text file:
You can make a little code or something that allows you to store their data as plain text, and then put it in a file like this:
to write (this will also create a new file named nameOfFile.txt, so you can automate it):

```
myTextFileHandler = Open('nameOfFile.txt', "w+") #open (and create, if it doesn't already exist) the file
myTextFileHandler.write("text in file") #rewrites the entire file to text
myTextFileHandler.close() #close file
```

to open:

```
myTextFileHandler = Open('nameOfFile.txt', "r") #open the file, but to read it
textInFile = myTextFileHandler.read() #returns text in the file
myTextFileHandler.close()
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but how does it import the text in the lines to entry's?

Comment: it just sets the text file's entire text to what you write, if you want to append, use myTextFileHandler = Open('nameOfFile.txt', "a"), then use the same myTextFileHandler.write('appended text'). it will aped the text to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the button function of tkinter module. For example:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

B1=Button(text="Click here")
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't mean that. I mean that the buttons also function like making a project by making a file of it that contains all the information done and saves it and then they can work further on the project.